# Why datetime, timedelta gives different values

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I have a .mat file with a column of numbers which represents dates relative to Jan-1-2014. I am trying to convert them to absolute dates. Here is when I tried it with individual values:

```
start = datetime(2014,1,1,0,0,0)
new = start + timedelta(days=342.41666667)
# 2014-12-09 10:00:00.000288
new = start + timedelta(days=342.420138888850)
# 2014-12-09 10:04:59.999997
```

However, when I iterate it through a loop for the entire array:

```
n = time.size
start = datetime(2014,1,1,0,0,0)
time_new = np.zeros(n,dtype = datetime)
ind = 0
for i in time:
    time_new[ind] = start + timedelta(days = i[0]) 
    ind = ind + 1

# time[0:2] ---array([[342.41666667],
#                     [342.42013889]])
# time_new[0:2] --- array([datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 9, 9, 59, 59, 999997),
#                          datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 9, 10, 4, 59, 999997),
```

The converted time for the first value is 2 seconds behind here (2014, 12, 9, 9, 59, 59,) as compared to the former one (2014-12-09 10:00:00.000288). I am unable to understand as to why a difference should come. Please help.

Comment: cannot reproduce your output for time_new. also, have a look at [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate).

Comment: make sure that np displays all the data there is - it may truncate non-so-significant numbers to something for displaying it.

Answer (score 0):

When you printed out `time[0:2]`, the value got rounded to 8 decimal places, which corresponds approximately to the millisecond level. However, the calculation is done on the full value, which is slightly different (in this case, by ~0.3ms).

How to resolve this depends on what exactly you need. If you know the resolution of the data, and it's millisecond or coarser, you can simply round to the nearest millisecond.

If you know the actual values for a few of the rows, you can check how closely those match the expected values. For instance, were you expecting the first row to be 2014-12-09 10:00? If so, you're only 3 microseconds out, which may be acceptable (or you may be able to use rounding for the rest).

If you need more precise conversion, you'll probably need to check what the precision is in your input, whether it's binary (IEEE float) or a decimal number, then proceed accordingly.

---

One unrelated improvement; rather than calculating `ind` manually, you can use:

```
for ind, i in enumerate(time):
    time_new[ind] = start + timedelta(days = i[0])
```